# How to remove cxf 'tmu:Timestamp' from SOAP header

Tags: java, soap, service, cxf, ws-security

I have created a java SOAP ws client for a SOAP web service which expects a username and a password inside a usernametoken element. I used cxf(3.3.2) to create my web service client.I have added as a dependecy cxf-rt-ws-security.My client code looks like this:

```
BindingProvider bp=(BindingProvider) port;

bp.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.USERNAME, username);
bp.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.PASSWORD, password);
```

The problem is that the cxf automatically adds the 'tmu:Timestamp' element at the SOAP header, but the web service does not like it, and I receive "An error occurred when verifying security for the message."
If I remove manually the 'tmu:Timestamp' element and send the request with SOAP UI, the request is sucessfully processed by the webservice.

My soap header looks like this:

```
<soap:Header>
   <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="true">
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-254d999a-5835-49ae-8acf-1f0d8821881b">
                    <wsu:Created>2020-06-13T11:47:23.160Z</wsu:Created>
                    <wsu:Expires>2020-06-13T11:52:23.160Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-39e0a8f0-b3b3-4225-8270-375681fc1866">
                <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
```

I tried to remove the 'wsu:Timestamp' element with a SOAPHandler but it failed.
Any help will be usefull. :)